# Display a div based on a sibling's height

Tags: jquery

I've searched and tried different things but can't seem to get the needed effect. I'm very new to jQuery thus need your input. Basically if one of the `.handouts-sidebar` divs is taller than 250px I need to display a **View all** button. There are multiple divs with `.handouts-sidebar` class. Each has a sibling button `.btn-popup` which is initially hidden.

HTML Structure

```
<div class="content-sidebar">
   <div class="handouts-sidebar">September's Handouts</div>
   <a class="btn-popup">View all</a>
</div>
<div class="content-sidebar">
   <div class="handouts-sidebar">October's Handouts</div>
   <a class="btn-popup">View all</a>
</div>
...


<script type="text/javascript">
    var div = jQuery(".handouts-sidebar").height();
    if (div > 245 ) {
      jQuery(".handouts-sidebar").next().show();
    }
</script>
```

Help! Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting any console errors?

Comment: No, none. I might be approaching this wrongly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$('a').hide();
$('.handouts-sidebar').each(function(){
    var div = $(this).height();
    alert("The height of sidebar is " + div);
    if (div > 245) {
      $(this).siblings().show();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content-sidebar">
   <div class="handouts-sidebar">September's HandoutsLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
   </div>
   <br>
   <a class="btn-popup">View all (i am displayed)</a>
</div>
<br>
<div class="content-sidebar">
   <div class="handouts-sidebar">October's Handouts</div>
   <br>
   <a class="btn-popup">View all</a>
</div>
...
```

Comment: Thank you soo much, this worked exactly as expected!

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery( ".handouts-sidebar" ).load(function() {
        var div = jQuery(".handouts-sidebar").height();
        if (div > 245 ) {
        jQuery(this).next().show();
        }
       });
    });
```

it may because you are not including ready function. if it doesn't work try to include ready function in your code

Comment: I just tested the previous comment and it worked but will test this as well out of curiosity. Thank you!